# java program with special characters and database

Tags: java, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, character

First of all i know that this problem is known, and have a lot of answers, but mine is little bit different or unusual.

So, i'm using `Eclipse SDK Version: 3.7.1`, and i'm developing java app (JRE 1.7) which will work with database.

Since application is in **Croatian language** I have problems with special characters - **č**,**ć**,**đ** and their insert into DB (mysql dbms, embedded with xampp).

However, i know little about encoding stuff, and i tried to set DB to `cp1250_croatian_ci`, `UTF8_unicode_ci`, `UTF8_general_ci`, `latin2_croatian_ci`, but sadly I had same problem with each of those. (is it mandatory to `SET NAMES utf8` (or something like that) after each connection to DB?)

Also, i want to point it out, that inserting (**č**,**ć**,**đ**) inside phpMyAdmin works fine.

So if i want to insert into DB characters **č**,**ć**,**đ** they are represented as **?**. So basicly that means that encoding or charset or something else is problem.

Also I'm using JDBC driver: `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin` 
From: [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j.html)

I want to mention that I didn't have problems, while DB was hosted on godaddy.com server

In addition project text encoding (in Eclipse) is set to "Inherited from container (CP1250)", also I tried with `UTF-8` but that didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do as follow
1 first you should set the mysql encodding to utf-8;
2 second when you connection db you should set the connection properties as follow
you can try this
`jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/yourDBName?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncode=UTF-8`

I think when you use the jdbc connection may be you lost the `useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncode=UTF-8`

Comment: @chunxiao but this did not work for me, I've triplechecked the sources via debug in my app, but Slovenian letter **Č** still converts to **?** when I insert/change record. Do you have some other idea(s)?